# How to show on the console XML http-response or any of its values

Tags: xml, wso2, httprequest, wso2-streaming-integrator

I have a WSO2 Stream Processor App that makes an http-resquest and receives a http-response:

```
@sink(type='http-request', sink.id='sinkid',  publisher.url='http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx', @map(type='xml', @payload('{{payloadBody}}')))
define stream SomeStream (payloadBody String, method string, headers string);

@source(type='http-response', sink.id='sinkid', http.status.code='200', 
@map(type='xml', @attributes(parval='parval')))
define stream responseSomeStream(parval string);
```

How can I extract any of the data to the console? I tried several ways but none has worked.

What I get on the console after sending the payload is:

```
{org.wso2.extension.siddhi.map.xml.sourcemapper.XmlSourceMapper} - Xpath: 'parval did not yield any results. Hence dropping the event : <resp action="read" units="S" user="TheUser" password="xxxxxxx" error="0"><val nodetype="16" node="2" display="u09 S5 Temp." name="u09 S5 Temp." stat="Online" statcode="2" error="0" pending="false" parval="-26.0" units="degc" units_index="4"> -26.0°C</val></resp> (Encoded)
```

I would like to extract some of the parameters from this XML response such as statcode, parval or units.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with the mapping you have provided and as mapping is incorrect mapper is dropping the incoming event. Inside the @map annotation @attribute section you should provide correct xpath mappings to extract the attributes you need.Please refer [these](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/siddhi-map-xml/blob/master/component/src/test/java/org/wso2/extension/siddhi/map/xml/sourcemapper/XmlSourceMapperTestCase.java#L443) testcases where it performs custom mappings with xpath expressions.

Comment: I do not know about **xpath**, as I haven't specifyed any URN in the payload. My payload is something simple like: <cmd action="read" units="S" user="XXXX" password="XXXXXXX"><val nodetype="16" node="2" /></cmd>, so I do not know exactly how to deal with it. I'll check the test cases you provide to try to understanfd how it works.